# Image Insertion not working properly. It is coming on the window as a frame but not loading the specific image i want to add to the frame

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I want to see the image on the frame but my image is not loading on the frame.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        tk.Label(self,text="",width=30,height=20,bg="#5CDB95",font=
        ("Vineta BT",20,"bold","italic","underline")).pack(side=TOP)
        self.img  = Image.open("down.png") 
        self.img = img.resize((800, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
        photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.lab=Label(image=photo)
        self.lab.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.3)
```

Comment: Which error did you get from: `self.img = img.resize(...`

Comment: Use `self.photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`.

Comment: Have you read through the answers at the following link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091

Comment: i used  'return imgview(self)' then it worked..i have not written it before